# Проверить загрузился ли график на странице

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот я эмулирую нажатие кнопки на HTML-странице с помощью:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(...).сlick();
```

И все работает хорошо, за исключением одной небольшой проблемки.
На странице есть график, при загрузки странице, сначала загружается основной HTML, потом скрипты, потом данные для графика.

То есть кнопка на графике как бы загружается не сразу, и для того, чтобы не вызвать функцию:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class_button").сlick();
```

Раньше, чем в HTML-коде появится класс отвечающий за эту кнопку, условно "class_button", я проверяю поиском по HTML наличие этого класса и только после вызываю сlick().

И все работает замечательно, за исключением проблемки: даже, если я дождусь наличия класса кнопки в HTML-коде и нажму ее - она нажмется, НО это может произойти немного раньше, чем сам браузер отобразит сам график и кнопку на нем на странице и получится такая ситуация:

click() я вызвал, кнопка нажалась, но так как визуально график еще не был отображен на странице браузера, то браузер начинает ее отображать и когда завершает процесс отображения, как бы сбрасывает мою нажатую кнопку в значение по умолчанию.

Вот вопрос: а как можно определить, что браузер визуально уже сформировал на странице график с кнопкой на ней ?

PS: сайт не мой, это сторонний сайт.

Comment: Как загружаете график? Тегом IMG?

Comment: а кнопку вы как дожидаетесь?

Comment: @EzioMercer, график загружает браузер, как собственно и всю страницу.

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, в инструменте разработчика я посмотрел класс кнопки и по мере формирования HTML-кода (или DOM по другому ?) я проверяю его на наличие этого класса в коде HTML.

Comment: Вы не поняли меня) График  - это просто картинка? Т.е. просто обычный `<img src="" />`?

Comment: @EzioMercer, пока что плохо разбираюсь в JS, но график скорее всего непросто вставленная картинка - это отрендеренные данные в виде картинки, скажем так. То есть сервер высылает браузер таблицу значений, а браузер уже строит график по эти значениям и выводит на экран.

Comment: @Staxcelrom это понятно, что по классу обращаетесь. На каком этапе? просто в консоли набираете? у вас есть доступ к скрипту? или пишете плагин для чужой страницы?

Comment: Это был вопрос про HTML, а не JS)) Что значит скорее всего? Сайт не ваш?)) Вы точно должны знать как рисуется график у вас. Если вам высылаются данные и вы анимированно их рисуете, то вам надо свою ф-ию вызывать в конце анимации. Если это просто картинка то надо слушать событие `onload` у картинки

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, я немного не уточнил, я использую CEF/С++, то есть у меня есть Callback каждого изменения HTML и грубо говоря при каждом изменение проверяю наличие класса.

Comment: @EzioMercer, сайт не мой конечно :)  Я что то даже не подумал уточнить эту информацию.

Comment: Ну вам тогда надо разбираться как работает этот сайт) Может быть там используется какая-та библиотека и он "выстреливает" каким-то событием по окончанию. Просто так по описанию не думаю что вам что-то подскажут дельное